# How to translate all text in svg container that are already rotated

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rotation, translation

Is there a short way of adding the translate to the text's transform attr without removing the rotation?

currently I add rotation when the text is created:

```
.attr('transform', rotate(270 xValue, yValue);
```

Note that this is done in a for loop since there are numerous texts

but later on the user should be able to drag the text horizontally. Dragging one text should move all the texts across. Doing the following removes the rotate attribute from above:

```
svgContainer.selectAll("text").attr("transform", "translate(" + [tx, ty] + ")");
```

is there a short way where I can select all the text and just append the translate attr to the rotate? Or do I need to loop through all the Texts and manually change each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just came to a working solution:

I've placed all the text inside a "g" element. and then translated the "g" element.